# MySQL: IF t1.row1 = t1.row2 INSERT INTO t2

Tags: mysql

I have three tables, `t1`, `t2` and `t3`.

Table 1 includes 'listings' and the images associated with the listings via the ID. They are both identified by looking at the `type`

```
id: 1
postId: NULL
type: listing

id: 2
postId: NULL
type: listing

id: 3
postId: 1
type: image

id: 4
postId: 1
type: image

id: 5
postId: 2
type: image
```

Table 2 also contains listing and image associations, which looks like this:

```
id: 1
listingId: 1
type: imageasoc
imgId: 3

id: 2
listingId: 1
type: imageasoc
imgId: 4

id: 3
listingId: 2
type: imageasoc
imgId: 5
```

When `t1.id` matches `t1.postId`, I want to add a new row in `t2`, which will include `t1.id` and the `id` of the `t1.postId` row, plus a string '`imageasoc`' (as you'll see in the example above)

I have the code below but I need it turning into an `INSERT INTO` statement, I have tried but the syntax/formatting is always wrong :(

```
UPDATE  t2
LEFT JOIN
        t1
ON      t1.id = t1.postId
SET     t2.listingId = t1.id, t2.type = 'imageasoc', t2.imgId = id of t1.postID 
WHERE   t1.type = 'image'
```

I hope I've explained myself enough, thanks!

Comment: At first you should separate your listings and images

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. What are the relationships of those tables? Where's t3? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can do this with an INSERT...SELECT statement:

```
INSERT INTO t2(listingId, type, imgId)
SELECT t1.id, 'imageasoc', t1.postId
FROM t1
WHERE t1.id = t1.postId
AND t1.type = 'image';
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, although this doesn't achieve what is asked in the question (my bad, seems as though I was complicating things for everyone including myself) I am now using this statement to achieve what I want in a simplified way! Is it still acceptable to mark as answer?

Comment: I would say it would be a very nice thing to do.